# Embed blob Image from database by phpMailer

Tags: php, image, email, blob, phpmailer

I have images saved in database as BLOB data. How do i embed them into html email using phpMailer?

PhpMailer has a function to embed normal images by using AddEmbeddedImage and it requires "path", "cid" & "name", all i have is a string of blob data so it won't work. The only way i can think of is temporarily generate an image from the string before using AddEmbeddedImage, however fear it might increase execution time.

Does anyone has a better idea please?

Answer (score 0):

There's `AddStringAttachment()` which is undocumented in the main PHPmailer docs. It allows attachments from a string instead of a file. Don't know offhand if you can then refer to this attached image via the `src="cid:..."` stuff, but at least you COULD attach the file to the email without having to write it out to a temp file first.

There's a little blurb about it in the phpmailer tutorials here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial

Comment: Thanks Marc, i tried that and the email did get attached fine however i don' know how to get the CID to link the image into the email.

Comment: It's not undocumented; [it's right here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment).